# how to get each looped elements in rails to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to get picture of current clicked id its below table row. but it always comes in under the first row in the table. I want to show image below the clicked Id.Help me out to figure this mess.

my ruby on rails code is....

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Address</th>
   </tr>
   <% @student.each do |stu|%>
    <tr>
     <td><%= link_to stu.id ,'#', :onclick => "showImage()"%></td>
     <td><%= stu.name></td> 
     <td><%= stu.address%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='3'><div id="image" style="display: none"><%= image_tag stu.image %></div></td></tr>
    <% end %>
 </table>
```

`javascript` code :

```
<script>
   function showImage(){
     document.getElementByID("image").style.display='none';
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Reason being you have not set any dynamic id of your div contains image so here try this:

1-

```
   <% @student.each do |stu|%>
    <tr>
     <td><%= link_to stu.id ,'#', :onclick => "showImage(stu.id)"%></td>
     <td><%= stu.name></td> 
     <td><%= stu.address%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='3'><div id="<%=stu.id%>" style="display: none"><%= image_tag stu.image %></div></td></tr>
    <% end %>
```

2- In script tag change following:

```
<script>
   function showImage(image_id){
     document.getElementByID(image_id).style.display='block';
   }
</script>
```